# Create a complex dictionary using multiple lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

Lets say I have three lists and want to create a dictionary using items from the lists as keys and values. I want it to look like this:

```
main_dic = {'FL-01':{'existing': 22, 'proposed': 47}, 'FL-01P': {'existing': 5, 'proposed': 8}, 'P04A': {'existing': 14, 'proposed': 38}, 'P05': {'existing': 7, 'proposed': 95}}
```

So, here are my three lists:

```
units = ['FL-01','FL-01P','P04A','P05']
existing = [22,5,14,7]
proposed = [47, 8, 38, 95]
```

I start by setting and empty dictionary

```
 main_dic = dict()
```

Now is where I get confused, because I need them to stay in order. I guess I could zip the existing and proposed together, but this is just a simple example and if I added a fourth list, say `future = [4, 7, 91, 26]`, then that would not work. I want to iterate threw the units list first since they will be the key to the primary dictionary and use `setdefault(k, v)` somehow but I am not sure how to correctly apply this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were correct about using `zip`:

```
units = ['FL-01','FL-01P','P04A','P05']
existing = [22,5,14,7]
proposed = [47, 8, 38, 95]

d = {u: {'existing': e, 'proposed': p} for u, e, p in zip(units, existing, proposed)}

print(d)
# {'FL-01': {'existing': 22, 'proposed': 47},
#  'FL-01P': {'existing': 5, 'proposed': 8},
#  'P04A': {'existing': 14, 'proposed': 38},
#  'P05': {'existing': 7, 'proposed': 95}}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. For some reason I thought I could only zip 2 lists at a time and didn't consider using dictionary comprehension. Thanks.